# Uninitialized constant error while deleting multiple connected records from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following database. After User registers to a site a new GalleryPhoto is created for him. He can have only one GalleryPhoto in which he can store multiple photos.

These are models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :gallery_photos, :dependent => :delete
  has_many :photos, :through => :gallery_photos

  after_create :setup_gallery

  def setup_gallery
    GalleryPhoto.create(userId: self.id, name: self.email)
   end
end

class GalleryPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :photos, :dependent => :delete_all
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery_photo
end
```

After I want to delete user:

```
def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
end
```

I receive the following error on that line:

```
NameError in UsersController#destroy
uninitialized constant User::GalleryPhotos
```

Gallery is created successfully after user registers and he can add images to it.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify this line

```
has_one :gallery_photos, :dependent => :delete
has_many :photos, :through => :gallery_photos
```

to

```
has_one :gallery_photo, :dependent => :delete
has_many :photos, :through => :gallery_photo
```

Comment: Thank you. So simple and I was looking in those lines for last two hours :)